# How to eliminate humidity / bad smell on an apartment?

Tags: home, air, smell

My current apartment has a Central Air System, which means the same ducts are used for cold and warm air. I have noticed the weird humidity smell that comes out of the ducts and fill the apartment with it ONLY when the heater is on.

I'm looking for solutions to eliminate the source of that smell. I'm not sure if a dehumidifier would work. I post this hopping someone with the same problem as me has found a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Some ducted air systems contain a **filter** which must be cleaned or replaced periodically. However if it is a shared system the smells can be coming from someone else's apartment, and you can't do much about that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have noticed the weird humidity smell that **comes out of the ducts**

I guess that the Central Air System is not your property and you are not responsible for its maintenance.

Since the stink seems to come out of the system itself, you should get the proper specialists to perform the proper maintenance. In the simple case, just a filter needs to be cleaned / replaced.

If you are unlucky, there are deposits of God knows what inside the system, tubes... and a serious maintenance work will have to be done.

---

About the humidity, there are two discussions.

1. If the air system brings in fresh air from outside, then the system should have a dehumidifier installed at the entrance air duct, to disallow the growth of mold inside the tubes.
2. To handle the humidity in your apartment locally, just use de-humidifier(s). A search using your preferred search engine will reveal a (wide) range of options, depending on your area of residence.

---

Additionally, especially after you deal with the source of humidity, make a thorough cleaning of the apartment, searching for all (hidden) places where the mold could have built up. Even with dry air, the mold might still prove dangerous to the health of the inhabitants.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem and we have a shared system.

We now make sure the filters get changed regularly and the ducts get cleaned out too, but that is not a 100% either. We still get smells from our neighbours!   It works to a degree, but it is better than nothing? Not exactly!

We now use a diffuser in our place. Some of the stronger and enjoyable scents work like a charm.

We use [Saje](https://www.saje.com/ca/diffusers-and-blends/) products only because I get a discount, it is Canadian and is 100% natural plant based products.  Others may be equally good.

Give it a shot as it won’t hurt to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The bad smell is coming from high humidity in your room. My advice would be to try to extract as much 'wetness' as possible out of that room, which will naturally destroy the odors. Get something like DampRid (lots of similar brands). We had a room that was flooded and had extremely bad humidity (e.g. you could smell the humidity coming from the concrete, walls, etc). Added Damprid and a week later it collected a liter of water that was trapped inside that room. No more bad smells afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

personally when i used to live in an apartment my mom would put baking soda the one that has a scent that's optenial you can even put it on carpet and leave it overnight and when you wake up vacuum the whole place and the apartment should be fresh.